How do I migrate Bot with related Flow routing?
How do I migrate Bot with related Flow routing?
Looks like when I migrate Bot with corresponding Flow, they are not connected after deployment to another org.
I don't understand why this is happenning and how this can be fixed and if this can be automated in any way.

Looks like Flow for redirection to bot has hard-coded Bot Id inside, which prevents it from being properly migrated to another environment.
While there is no visible error for the end user like 'invalid cross-reference id' which you may usually expect, the flow is not working correctly and is not correctly connected to the bot and to the service channel since they have different Ids on a different org.
It is possible to use SOQL to query correct service channel Id and to write some sed script to replace service channel id with a correct but unfortunately it is not possible to retrieve Bot id neither by SOQL nor Tooling API.
Metadata API also doesn't expose any information about Bot record Id.
So looks like this is not possible to automate and the Flow should be manually created or edited on the target org.
